# Windows 10 Security/Privacy settings

Tags: windows-10

Regarding Windows 10. I found this:

[image]

What am I reading there?

Comment: Its just pointing out how much Windows 10 will be spying (collecting data) on you.

Answer (score 1):

As @Moab said, it's showing all the new Windows 10 'features' which will collect data about you.

**Telemetry**, the highlight of the image, is just a fancy word for Microsofts automatic sending of diagnostic data (ie crash reports, logs, and more) to their servers. There is no way (except for a registry edit) to disable it completely without a third party app (unless you're on Windows 10 enterprise).

---

Thankfully, there's **[O&O ShutUp10](http://www.oo-software.com/de/shutup10)**.

This app is wonderful for easily disabling all the tracking 'features' of Windows 10. I realize you asked what you were looking at, but I'm going to assume you (or anyone) reading would want to know how to disable what you were looking at.

What's nice about this particular app is it actually explains each setting by clicking on it, so you can decide for yourself if you want to disable it.

Also, don't be scared off by the German, the app comes in English as well.

> [image]

|

> [image]

|

> [image]